# String is not a subtype of ()

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to create a block that I could enter parameters but had no return (a type block void). We know that the structure of a block that does not have parameters and not return anything is this:

```
var block: () -> () = {
//Hello World goes here
}
```

In the case of a block with parameters, but does not return anything, we can use this command:

```
var bloco7: (String) -> () = {
   //Hello World goes here
}
```

But we have two problems: The first is that this code not working, the second is this code only works if we call a temporary variable like this:

```
var bloco7: (String) -> () = {
   $0//I only need to call
   //Hello World goes here and all the things OK
}
```

I wonder know why this is happening, it does not seem to make much sense ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two parts here.

First, we declare the type of our closure:

```
var bloco7: (String) -> ()
```

`bloco7` is a variable whose type is `(String) -> ()` (a closure which takes a string and returns `nil`.  We don't define the name of the parameter here.  The parameter is named by the "closure literal syntax" so-to-speak.

So, if we want to have an inline closure, we can later to:

```
var bloco7: (String) -> () = {
    yourArgument in // <-- here we named the parameter, it's called 'yourArgument'
    println(yourArgument)
}
```

But it's important to note that we aren't defining the variable's name when we are declaring `bloco7` and its type.  Keep in mind that we can assign methods and functions to closure variables.

For example, given this function:

```
func sayHello(name: String) -> Void {
    println("Hello, " + name + "!")
}
```

We can actually have `bloco7` point to this function:

```
bloco7 = sayHello
```

And now, the following two lines actually do the exact same thing:

```
sayHello("World")
bloco7("World")
```

The important take-away here is that the argument names are irrelevant to the type of closure's type.  The argument names are part of the value we assign to the variable, not part of its type.

Answer (score 1):

In the first,you need to do it like tis

```
var bloco7: (String) -> () = {
    input in
    //Do something with input
}
```

`bloco7` type is:`(String)->()`

`{}` type is :`() -> ()`

**They do not match,so you get an error**

But in the second way,you use $0,swift know that it has a input,it will match.Match $0 to the input `String`,so type is right